# Extract value from header string

Tags: php, regex, email

I am writing a code to read bounced emails from inbox. I am getting the body of the email like so:

```
$body = imap_body($conn, $i);
```

After I get the body string, I split it into an array with explode.

```
$bodyParts = explode(PHP_EOL, $body);
```

The bounced emails that I am concerned with, they all have a particular header set i.e. X-OBJ-ID. I can loop through `$bodyParts` to check if that particular header is set or not, but how do I get it's value if the header exists. Currently, the header string looks like this for those bounced emails which had that header set:

```
"X-OBJ-ID: 24\r"
```

So, basically my question is: How do I extract 24 from the above string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookbehinds can be helpful in such cases

```
/(?<=X-OBJ-ID: )\d+/
```

- `(?<=X-OBJ-ID: )` look behind. Ensures that the digits is preceded by `X-OBJ-ID:`
- `\d+` Matches digits.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dP9uU7/1)

**Example**

```
preg_match("/(?<=X-OBJ-ID: )\d+/", "X-OBJ-ID: 24\r", $matches);
print_r($matches)
=> Array ( 
    [0] => 24 
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

or you can do it via regular expression

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like so:

```
$str = "X-OBJ-ID: 24\r";
preg_match('X-OBJ-ID:\s+(\d+)', $str, $re);
print($re);
```

This should match your string and store the `24` within a capture group which will be then made accessible through `$re`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str)
```

it removes all the non numeric characters from the string

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<?php
$string = '"X-OBJ-ID: 24\r"';
preg_match_all('^\X-OBJ-ID: (.*?)[$\\\r]+^', $string, $matches);
echo !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : 'No matches found';
?>
```

**See it working here http://viper-7.com/kuMyVh**